# Look for data where child doesn't exisit

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to look in Table C for those inspectors who have got ParentID but not child.

Table A has both parent and child data. Parent ID 0 is for parents and child has their parent ID.

In Table C, one inspector can have many parents and many childs.

I need to run a query to look for those inspectors who have got parents but not child.

```
Table A               Table B          Table C           
--------             -------           -------           
DisciplineID(PK)    InspectorID(PK)     ID (PK)        
ParentID                                DisciplineID(FK)            
                                        InspectorID (Fk)
```

[image]

```
     Table A                 Table C
```

In above mentioned data, Inspector 7239 and 7240 only have parent but not child. So query should return those two not 7242 because he has both parent and childs.

Comment: You have two `Table C`.

Comment: no i don't know the purpose of TableB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT c.ID, c.InspectorID, c.DisciplineID
FROM dbo.TableC c
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableA a
    WHERE a.DisciplineID = c.DisciplineID 
      AND a.ParentID = 0  -- parent exists
)
AND NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableC c2
    WHERE c.InspectorID = c2.InspectorID 
     AND  c.ID <> c2.ID -- look for another record with this InspectorID 
      AND EXISTS        
      (
          SELECT 1 FROM dbo.TableA a
          WHERE a.DisciplineID = c2.DisciplineID 
          AND a.ParentID <> 0  -- no child exists
      )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a pre-qualifying query per discipline based on those having a count of entries that HAVE a parent ID = 0 but also no records as child... Join that result to your TableC

```
SELECT 
      c.ID, 
      c.InspectorID, 
      c.DisciplineID
   FROM 
      dbo.TableC c
         JOIN ( select
                      a.DisciplineID
                   from
                      TableA a
                   group by
                      a.DisciplineID
                   having 
                         sum( case when a.ParentID = 0 then 1 else 0 end ) > 0
                     AND sum( case when a.ParentID > 0 then 1 else 0 end ) = 0 ) qual
         on c.DisciplineID = qual.DisciplineID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.INSPECTORID FROM TABLEA A 
LEFT JOIN TABLEC CHILD ON CHILD.DISCIPLINEID = A.DISCIPLINEID
LEFT JOIN TABLEC PARENT ON PARENT.DISCIPLINEID = A.PARENTID
JOIN TABLEB B ON A.INSPECTORID = B.INSPECTORID
WHERE (A.PARENTID = 0 AND CHILD.DISCIPLINEID IS NOT NULL)
```